# Any way to requests self data while webscraping?

Tags: python

While using requests, I noticed that the requested data was always just raw html code. Is there any way for the requested data to be your own data? For example, the data that is returned is the same as would be when you inspect a tab?

Ex:

```
import requests as req
ip = req.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
```

It doesn't return my actual IP, instead it returns one from presumably wherever the server is requesting the website

Comment: Why do you need to use `ipify.org` for that? You can get the client IP directly.

Comment: For this example you can pass your own IP in the request header, i.e. `requests.get('https://api.ipify.org', headers={"x-forwarded-for": "1.2.3.4"})`.

Comment: What's the point? It will just return `1.2.3.4`

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but if it is a service that validates the client IP address it will bypass that check. I assumed that `ipify.org` is just an example.

Comment: using sockets gives the wrong IP for some reason.

Comment: @Selcuk He referred to the returned data. `ipify.org` is an API for finding out your public IP (like whatismyip.com).